# What's wrong with this var statement declaring a variable with a dot in the name?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and I get an error saying that my code is missing semicolons on line 2. What semicolons does it need? I already put semicolons.

```
var success = function(){
    var wx.varx = $scope.vr;
    $state.go("/there");
};
```

Comment: You can't define variable as `var wx.varx`, remove `.` or `var wx = { varx :  $scope.vr };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with that line is that it's simply invalid. The error message is just the parser doing its best to figure out what's going on.

`var` declares a *variable*. Literal variable names (*IdentifierName* in the spec) cannot contain a `.`.

If you have an in-scope `wx` identifier referencing an object and want to set a property on it, remove `var`:

```
wx.varx = $scope.vr;
```

If you want to create a new variable, remove the `.` from the name.

```
var wxvarx = $scope.vr;
```

If you want to *create* a `wx` variable and an object containing `varx` as a property:

```
var wx = {
    varx: $scope.vr
};
```

Comment: I can't redefine wx because it already has a bunch of data. I just need to set a new property.

Comment: @Books: That would be option 1 above, then: `wx.varx = $scope.var;`

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
var wx={};
wx.varx =  $scope.vr;
```

You cannot use variable directly as an object

Comment: If object already exists then you should not re declare again

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare an object property directly using

```
var wx.varx
```

As the object does not exist at this point. Instead you need to declare the object (wx) and set varx.

```
var vx = {
    varx: $scope.vr
};
```

Comment: wx object exists. It just varx property that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: In that case just remove 'var'. A property is part of the object and thus does not need to be declared separately using var as it shares the scope of the object itself.